# passing text from an Array to UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

i want to pass some html i have saved as string and stored in an array into a UIWebView. 
can anyone help me on how to do this because all i can find is how to grab it from the internet rather than already stored data

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to provide generated HTML content to a UIWebView? If so, you'll want to use `-[UIWebView loadHTMLString:baseURL:]`. You can pass your HTML string for the first argument, and nil in for the second argument.

Comment: You might want to pass something meaningful for the second argument, however, at least if you have something meaningful to pass.