# Passing Array to UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I currently am pulling directions from google and storing them into an array. I then have an integer for the amount of directions found, and have the forloop displaying them via NSLog properly (with the html included)

My question is, how do I make this into a UIWebView so that it properly displays this information in a list?

Here is my code so far:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *currentLoc = @"Hyannis, MA";
NSString *directionsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@, %@, %@&sensor=false", currentLoc, [self.selectedEvent objectForKey:@"eventAddress"], [self.selectedEvent objectForKey:@"eventCity"], [self.selectedEvent objectForKey:@"eventState"]];

directionsString = [directionsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

NSData *jsonResponse = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:directionsString]];

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponse options:kNilOptions error:&error];

self.directionsArray = [[[[jsonDict valueForKey:@"routes"] valueForKey:@"legs"] valueForKey:@"steps"] valueForKey:@"html_instructions"];

NSUInteger total = [self.directionsArray count];

for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    NSString *statusString = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"status"];
    NSLog(@"JSON Response Status:%@", statusString);

    NSLog(@"Direction: %@", [self.directionsArray objectAtIndex:i]);

}
```

Comment: Is this what you're wanting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713388/passing-text-from-an-array-to-uiwebview?rq=1

Comment: I don't see how that would work considering you're passing in a string not an array? I have an array of directions, each index of the array being a seperate direction.